# Python: how to read in text file into dictionary (repeating, mixed upper/lower keys)

Tags: python, dictionary, key, text-files, repeat

I have a file that looks like this:

```
wOrd1;codeA
WORD2;codeB
woRD1;codeC
word3;codeD
...
```

What's the "pythonic" way of creating from that file a dictionary like this:

```
{'word1':['codeA','codeC'],'word2':['codeB'],'word3':['codeD'],...}
```

Of course, this would work fine if I had unique keys:

```
myDict = dict(line.lower().strip().split(';', 1) for line in open("myInputFile",'r'))
```

Modify this statement or write a totally new one? Thx

Comment: *"Modify this statement or write a totally new one?"* - yes, that's what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong because you never create a list of related values and since you passed pairs with duplicated keys it will only accepts the first pair.

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to create the proper dictionary:

```
d={}

with open('file_name') as f:
   for line in f:
       w,code=line.split(';')
       d.setdefault(w,[]).append(code)
```